# My ubuntu randomly automatically logout after installing openbox

Tags: openbox

i got this error on my log, it keep logout automatically

already reinstalled openbox, but this still happen

btw i'm running ubuntu 12.04

```
ERROR: apport (pid 26391) Sun Mar  2 20:57:36 2014: gdbus call error: Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

ERROR: apport (pid 26391) Sun Mar  2 20:57:36 2014: debug: session gdbus call: 
ERROR: apport (pid 26391) Sun Mar  2 20:57:36 2014: this executable already crashed 2 times, ignoring
ERROR: apport (pid 28921) Sun Mar  2 20:59:46 2014: called for pid 26598, signal 6
ERROR: apport (pid 28921) Sun Mar  2 20:59:46 2014: executable: /usr/bin/openbox (command line "/usr/bin/openbox --startup /usr/lib/openbox/openbox-autostart\ OPENBOX")
ERROR: apport (pid 28921) Sun Mar  2 20:59:46 2014: gdbus call error: Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

ERROR: apport (pid 28921) Sun Mar  2 20:59:46 2014: debug: session gdbus call: 
ERROR: apport (pid 28921) Sun Mar  2 20:59:46 2014: this executable already crashed 2 times, ignoring
```

fixed by removing apport update-manager and update-manager-core

Comment: please add your solution as an answer instead and don't post SOLVED in the title, we have answers for a reason. We want to keep the questiion clear from the solution. So it's easy for any other user to follow.

Comment: So. Many. Bugs! A crashed application should fire off an apport bug. You seems to have been affected by two bugs - one crashing openbox and another crashing apport. So sad. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay its already fixed by removing apport, update-manager and update-manager-core
and btw i get the solution from [here](http://linuxg.net/fix-errors-cause-by-openbox-on-ubuntu-12-04/)

```
$ sudo apt-get remove apport update-manager update-manager-core
```

now my openbox run smoothly without problem