# Automatically being logged out in Lubuntu (openbox)

Tags: lubuntu, troubleshooting

I get automatically logged-out every now and then of my PC.

I use Lubuntu 14.04, which has openbox, LXDE. I didn't installed neither openbox nor LXDE by myself.

It happens when I turn-off the wifi, but also at other times.

I am not sure if it's a log-out or just something like Xorg crashing and being re-started.

How can I diagnose and repair this problem?

Would this solution work and what consequences would it have?

From [My ubuntu randomly automatically logout after installing openbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/428387/my-ubuntu-randomly-automatically-logout-after-installing-openbox):

```
$ sudo apt-get remove apport update-manager update-manager-core
```

Comment: You can take a look in your `/var/log/syslog`

Answer (score 1):

Some packages listed in that command (`update-manager` and `update-manager-core`) would remove your ability to update packages on your system, and that is definitely NOT recommended, so that solution would not work.

In my experience, generally if you can run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` from a terminal, you might solve the problem. This command downloads the newest versions of packages on your system and installs them, possibly fixing bugs such as this.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely Xorg is crashing on you and upstart relaunches the display manager which results in you being presented with a logon screen.

Check your Xorg log files they are `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` for the current session and `/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old` for the previous session. You will need to look into the .old file.

If you want to get really technical (as in C level system calls) you can switch to a text console, log on, `sudo su`, `strace -o /root/trc -ff -p 1` and then switch back to the GUI. When you get logged off switch back to the text console, interrupt strace with `Ctrl-C` and examine files `/root/trc.*`. Your answer may be somewhere there but the signal to noise ratio is fairly low.

Answer (score 0):

I have been getting logged out of Ubuntu as well. How I fixed it was, go into system settings, click on brightness and lock,set the timer to turn off screen when inactive to never. Then set the turn off lock screen to 1 hour or shut it off.
That solved my problem.Was getting logged out every 30 min. Hope this helps you.